# When use Route Attribute on Action Method, OnActionExecuting is not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In a Dotnet core 3 application when I use [Route] Attribute on Action Method then **OnActionExecuting** is not triggering.

**Action Method with Rout Attribute:**

```
[Route("Login/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Login(int id)
        {
            var vm = new AcccountLoginViewModel();
            vm.CityId= id;
            return View(vm);
        }
```

**OnActionExecuting:**

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
            filterContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("id", out object? id);

            if(id == null) {
                filterContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("CityId", out id);
                ViewBag.CityId = id;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.CityId = id;
            }
            

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=AdminHome}/{action=DashBoard}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(name: "Admins", areaName: "Admins", pattern: "Admins/{controller=AdminHome}/{action=DashBoard}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Cities}/{id?}");
            });
```

tried to add a route at startup.cs

`endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "customRout", pattern: "{action=Cities}/{id?}");`

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Waqas, route attribute will not influence the filter and also I have tested in my project. Maybe your project contains other problem, could you pls share a minimal repo which can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I can't see anything which defines the http method, so the app doesn't know when the endpoint should be invoked. You should use HttpGet/Post attribute alone or with combination with Route attribute